# Azure DevOps deployment pipeline - how do I find value to use for Linux image name?

Tags: linux, docker, azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline for a .NET Core app. The pipeline currently specifies `ubuntu-latest` as the Linux image name to use when building the Docker image. I want to change it to the latest version of Alpine. Is there are reference anywhere to the values that need to be used? And what is that value actually referring to - is it a reference name for a Linux image in the Docker Container Registry?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'd misunderstood the purpose of the `vmImageName` - I though it was specifying the Linux image that would be used by the deployed container. It's actually specifying a name from the following table, that determines the Linux version that will be used by the Azure DevOps build agent VM. It's used as a way of specifying a Microsoft-hosted agent for the build, that is automatically updated and maintained by Microsoft. The values come from the following table:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent

To change the OS used by the *docker container* when building the image, I had to change the tag for the .NET Core SDK and runtime images specified in my dockerfile, as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine3.12 AS build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine3.12 AS runtime
```

The full tag listings, describing how to specify which OS will be used by the .NET Core images, is found on both of the following pages under the heading "Full Tag Listing":

Runtime: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet

SDK: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)